# Update variable by feeding its value

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a TensorFlow model and I want to have the option to retrieve and update the weights (out of the checkpointing mechanism, that is). Since I may do this a number of times, I don't want to add nodes to the graph whenever I do it, but rather have some op(s) that I can call to do it. My idea was to have `tf.assign` ops using the same variable both for the updated variable and for the value, and provide the new weights values in the `feed_dict`; so something like this:

```
weights_assigns = [tf.assign(v, v) for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
weights_update = tf.group(*weights_assigns)

# Now to update the weights
weights = [...]  # List of new weight values
feed_dict = {v: w for v, w in zip(tf.trainable_variables(), weights)}
tf.run(weights_update_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

In my mind, this should take the values passed in `feed_dict` as current values of the variables and then store them through the `tf.assign` operations. However, this does not work and gives me some weird error about unexpected value types.

My current alternative is to have instead some auxiliary nodes, either variables or placeholders, and use as value in the assignment operations:

```
weights_updates = [tf.placeholder(v.dtype, v.get_shape()) for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
weights_assigns = [tf.assign(v, u) for v, u in zip(tf.trainable_variables(), weights_updates)]
weights_update_op = tf.group(*weights_assigns)

# Now to update the weights
weights = [...]  # List of new weight values
feed_dict = {u: w for u, w in zip(weights_updates, weights)}
tf.run(weights_update_op, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Is this really the only way to do this? Or is there some other obvious way I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, found that there is a load() method:

```
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    w = tf.get_variable('weights', shape=[3, 3], 
                        initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(dtype=tf.float32))
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        print('initial W:')
        print(sess.run(w))
        new_vals = np.reshape(np.arange(9, dtype=np.float32), (3,3))
        w.load(new_vals)
        print('updated W:')
        print(sess.run(w))
```

Maybe this helps?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my problem is that I actually want to persist the given value in the session, and to have it available in the next call to `run`. Giving the desired values in every single call to `run` would be possible, but not a practical solution for me.

Comment: Ok, found Variables have a load() method. Deleted confusing comments and updated answer with tested code.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. I would personally prefer to have an explicit op in the graph to do that since that way I could store it in some graph collection to run it later, but I guess that's how they made the API. Thanks!